# How to convert .s files to .mp4 files

Tags: video, video-conversion, video-codecs

I have `.s` video files from a DVR backup. I can only view them with an MCD player. 
I need the videos in a format like .mp4 or .avi or any other format so that I can process them. I have tried using VLC but didnt work.

Can somebody please suggest a way? It could be in Python or any other software.

Comment: I can't find any information about .s video file format. Could you install [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) and run `ffmpeg -i yourFile.s` to see the output ?
Maybe FFmpeg will be able to directly convert your file using `ffmpeg -i yourFile.s convertedFile.mp4`

Comment: From what I found the folder should also contain a converter application in addition to the player. You probably won’t be able to do anything without this special converter or player.

Comment: ffmpeg worked!! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @Nizwa I created a dedicated answer, as my comment appears to solve your problem. Did the conversion work, or were you just able to get the media informations ? You can mark the answer as accepted, so your question will appear as "answered"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) will be able to read your video files:

```
ffmpeg -i originalFile.s convertedFile.mp4
```

You can get media info of your file using only the input:

```
ffmpeg -i originalFile.s
```